# Heroku dyno using thin instead of unicorn

Tags: heroku, unicorn

I upgraded my app from Rails 3 to 4 and I'd like to start using Unicorn as my server. I've followed the Heroku documentation adding the Procfile and config/unicorn.rb, but when I push it runs thin.

=== web (2X): `bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`
web.1: up 2014/09/09 17:45:54 (~ 1m ago)

Thin isn't in my Gemfile and I'm wondering what other potential conflicts could exist to prevent Unicorn from loading.

[image]

Procfile:
bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

Comment: Could we see the source of your Procfile?

Comment: I think your Procfile is wrong, it should have a line like `web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb` (note the `web:` at the beginning).

Comment: Thanks Matt, that was it.

Comment: @matt make sure you answer the question so Walksalong can accept it. ;)